Adding a single column to each dataframe in a dictionary of dataframes
Ok so I have a dictionary of dataframes df_dict that looks like this
{'df ICU:1 ':      ICU: 1
 0           True
 1          False
 2           True
 3           True
 4           True
 5          False
 6           True
 7          False
 8           True
      
 [8 rows x 1 columns],
 'df ICU: 2':      ICU: 2
 0        True
 1        True
 2        True
 3        True
 4        True
 5        True
 6        True
 7        True
 8        True
     
 [8 rows x 1 columns],
 'df ICU: 3':      ICU: 3
 0         True
 1         True
 2         True
 3         True
 4         True
 5        False
 6         True
 7         True
 8         True
     
 [8 rows x 1 columns]}

I would like to add the exact column below Dx , which is part of another dataframe df that is not in the dictionary, to each of the dataframes in the dictionary.
0          AA
1          AA
2          AA
3          AB
4          AB
5          AA
6          AB
7          AA
8          AB
Name: Dx, Length: 8, dtype: object

This column and all columns in all dataframes have the same number of rows.
Is there any way at all to do this? I haven't been able to find an anwser despite multiple searches.

your questions is not very clear, try using the following;
dx_series = pd.Series(['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AB', 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'AB'], name='Dx')
for key in dict_of_dataframes:
dict_of_dataframes[key]['Dx'] = dx_series
